# How do I remove a fish smell from my freezer?

Tags: refrigerator, smell

Yesterday, the electricity was out for a while and I guess some of the fish in my freezer warmed up and juices started flowing out of its bag and into the vent. Now there is a fishy scent creeping up from the back of the fridge. Is this something I can just wait out or should I do something about it? I did clean out the freezer and everything looks immaculate in there now.

Comment: cut the lemon in half and put them on the egg shelf.

Answer (score 6):

After cleaning it well, put a piece of coal in the freezer; this will remove any smells from it within few hours, maybe a day.

I used to put a mid-sized piece of coal inside the refrigerator all the time. This was a piece of advice from my mother and always worked.

Comment: Will this help the smell coming from the back of the freezer? I put my nose to the back and I can smell the air coming out and it's definitely fishy. I don't have to pour anything down the vent inside the freezer to help combat this?

Comment: if this smell is coming from inside so this may help.

Comment: So your answer probably won't help my situation since my smell is coming from the back? The inside smells only a little but the air coming out from the back is what's really causing the stink.

Comment: yes, in this case i think you don't have except cleaning with water, but also try my solution, you will not lose anything but may at least help.

Comment: also an advice from my wife is to open the freezer, get out everything from it, power off the electricity and then clean well with water and drop some warm water inside, which should go through the back Hose, then keep its door open and let it like this for few hours,  I know it's a time consuming solution but will remove any smells.

Comment: Coal or some activated carbon?

Comment: like this http://www.climate-justice-now.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/coal.jpg

Comment: My mom used to keep a piece of coal in the refrigerator and freezer, and that seen to work. I know it's an old wives' tale but I keep coal in my freezer and refrigerator and I have no odors or bad smells.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a tray or pan that catches condensation beneath the fridge. It should just slide out. Try cleaning that.

Newspaper and kraft paper help absorb odors, so you can find some places to line with a folded newspaper or brown paper bag. Some layers under the ice cube tray and on the bottom of the freezer.

Baking soda also works, in an open container or just a whole open box.

If none of that does the trick ... I once fumigated a roach infested apartment with the refrigerator door open. Long story, but it seemed like a good idea at the time. The fridge was empty, unplugged, and full of roaches. My skin crawls just remembering that apartment. The net result was that the fridge smelled like roach spray. I had to run it with the door open for several days, empty, pouring cool air into the room, before the smell finally disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my units I had a smelly freezer. Cleaning  all the surfaces didn't seem to help. I had to unscrew the plastic lining on the bottom of it and there was some disgusting ooze underneath.  Probably from some meat juices that leaked there.

So keep looking or a spot where spoiled juices might have leaked